# Data Type for timer in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an application to count the timer on the dashboard, e.g. 01d 01h 01m, and after generating csv report it shows value "90060" which is in seconds. Now I want to import it into mysql db and then using some BI tool like Metabase to create dashboard to show the timer in "01d 01h 01m".

May I know what data type should I choose for storing the value "90060" in mysql, int, time or datatime?

Thanks.

Best Regards,
C

Answer (score 1):

Use `INT` for storing an integer.

You can convert it to the format you want this way:

```
mysql> select date_format(from_unixtime(90060), '%jd %kh %im') as time;
+--------------+
| time         |
+--------------+
| 001d 17h 01m |
+--------------+
```

See [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) in the manual.